# Docker and localhost seem not to connect as should

Tags: docker, localhost

So Im new to Docker and wanted to start a docker container with a apache system on it that should just show one simple "hello world" php-file.
I followed a youtube tutorial for that.

Now I could set up the container and I could run the image, I also connected the port of the container with the port outside, but it seems like its not working. 
My http://localhost:80 (<- I connected Port 80 to port 80 in the container) and nothing happened. 
Is it possible, that my firewall is killing the connection?

Here is the dockerfile and my php file:

PHP

```
<? php
echo "Hello World";
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.0-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

The tutorial is this one:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFl2mCHdv24

Unfortunately my knowledge is so limited, that I have not even an idea where to search for the probelm.

Edit:
After building my container I used

```
docker run -p 80:80 <name of container>
```

Thanks for taking your time

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the image with the -p option like:

```
docker run -p 80:80 <image name>
```

Expose is only working for internal docker image communication. -p then maps the host port to the container port:

```
-p <host_port>:<container_port>
```

Comment: This is what I did when I used the console to run the container.

Comment: windows or linux?